# Convert PDF url to Base64, error when open file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a pdf url to base64.

I have found this solution ( in other questions ) but it doens't work in my case:

```
convertToBase64(info: any, url: string) {
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: "blob" })
      .subscribe(blob => {
        console.log("blob ", blob)
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const binaryString = reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          //Here you can do whatever you want with the base64 String
          console.log("File in Base64: ", event.target.result);
          this.pdfBase64 = event.target.result
          this.service.sendMail(info, this.pdfBase64)
            .subscribe((data) => {
              console.log("data ", data)
            })
        };

        reader.onerror = (event: any) => {
          console.log("File could not be read: " + event.target.error.code);
        };
      });
  }
```

I have tried to encode my pdf url using a service found in the web and it works (I pass the base64 to a function to send a mail, and it works) while The base64 string that I obtain from the code didn't works. Infact when I tried to open it, it  give me back an error and also I noticed that the base64 from the code is smaller than other.

How can I trasform a pdf url in base64?

Comment: just maybe(!! I'm not sure) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL _Note: The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove data:*/*;base64, from the result._

Comment: that means if you remove the `File in Base64:  data:application/octet-stream;base64,` part from that string, it should successfully be decoded as intended